# Python/Django - How to get the page URL before navigating to a new view

Tags: python, django, url

I have a link that links to a url, like so:

`<a href="{% url 'sign_in' %}" title="Click here to sign in">Sign in</a>`

This links to a new view in Django, my URL pattern looks like this:

`url(r'^sign-in/', sign_in, name="sign_in")`

In my `sign_in` view, I would like to have access to the URL where the user originally clicked the link. Specifically, I would like to add this URL has a parameter called `returnUrl` to a new URL. My `sign_in` view can then redirect to this new URL, and the corresponding view will have access to the `returnUrl` parameter.

For example:

1. The user clicks 'Sign in'
2. The website navigates to example.com/sign-in/
3. The `sign_in` view redirects to `sign_in_page` adding the URL from step 1 as a parameter.
4. `sign_in_page` has access to the URL parameter.

How can I achieve this in Django? My views look like this...

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve


def sign_in(request):
    # I need the original URL the user came from here 
    # to add it as `returnUrl` below:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sign_in_page') + '?returnUrl=example.com/whatever')


def sign_in_page(request):
    return render(request, 'sign-in.html')
```

Please let me know if I'm going down a wrong and dark path by using a redirect. To me it seemed like the only way to add a URL parameter - which is important for my implementation. If you know of a way to do it without the redirect - let me know!

Comment: can you tell about the parameter? means how are you keeping it? and is the parameters different throughout the page?

Comment: The parameter called `returnUrl` needs to be the current URL when the user clicked on the "Sign in" link. Once the sign in process is complete, I can use this in my `sign_in_page` view to redirect the user back to the original page where they clicked on the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass data between views, you may use either POST data or GET. In your case GET data is what you want.
So you should use the following URL.

```
"{% url 'sign_in' %}?returnUrl={{request.path}}"
```

Then after in your view:

1. check if GET variable 'returnUrl' was sent
2. redirect to the next URL
3. else redirect to the default page

In the following example I am using Class based View inherited from FormView

```
def get_success_url(self):
    if self.request.GET.get('next', ''):
        return (self.request.GET.get('next', ''))
    return  reverse_lazy('experiment_list')
```

Note: make sure you include the following in your settings, to make sure you get the `request.path` variable in each template:

```
## example: settings.py
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # other items...
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    # other items...
)
```

Comment: Where does `{{next}}` come from and how can you ensure that value is the current URL the user is on?

Comment: For the django view that loads the template (html) with the link (<a> element).
For example you load a page with list of books(/books) and because user is Anonymous you have links to sign in (next="/books") so the interpret link will be /sign_in?next="/books"

Comment: I would like to add this to every page/view on the website by default, because the sign in button is on every page, is this possible?

Comment: add {{request.path}} In every page instead of {{next}} so you dont have to initialize the next var in every view

Comment: Great....!!!! Keep in mind, that working with classed based views has many benefits https://ccbv.co.uk/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect to referer, Then you can try like this

```
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

    def sign_in(request):
       # Do your logic here
       return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')`  returns nothing, do you know why this is?

Comment: Which version of django you are using?

Comment: Are you sure, your link is in the same django project or it will come from outside?

Comment: It's in the same project

Comment: A _Referer_ (note the unusual spelling) header is not sent by browsers if:
a) the referring resource is a local "file" or "data" URI. Or
b) an unsecured HTTP request is used and the referring page was received with a secure protocol (HTTPS).

Answer (score 2):

```
referer = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```

try this in the view where you need to get the previous url, hope this is what you are looking for